# cancelAlarm method not actually canceling my AlarmManager

Tags: java, android, service, alarm

I have used this `cancelAlarm` method from another reputable answer on stack, and it isn't getting the job done, and I am out of ideas of why this isn't working.

I have an activity where one button will start an alarm that will go off every given interval. I then have another button that will cancel that alarm. Here are the buttons first:

```
    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setupAlarm(10);
        }
    });

    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try{
                cancelAlarm(ALARM_ID);
            } catch(Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

And here are my `setupAlarm` and `cancelAlarm` methods:

```
private void setupAlarm(int seconds) {
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            MainActivity.this, ALARM_ID, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Calendar t = Calendar.getInstance();
    t.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

    int interval = seconds*1000;
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, t.getTimeInMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
    MainActivity.this.finish();
}

private void cancelAlarm(int alarmId){
    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmManager.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, alarmId, i, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(sender);
    sender.cancel();
}
```

I remembered to make another alarm manager with the same ID, and call `alarmManager.cancel(sender);` on the `PendingIntent` but it doesn't seem to do anything, because my service will start back up anyway.

AlarmReciever class:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    Context oAppContext = context.getApplicationContext();

    if (oAppContext == null) {
        oAppContext = context;
    }

    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(oAppContext, MyService.class);
    oAppContext.startService(serviceIntent);
}
}
```

MyService class:

```
public class MyService extends Service implements SensorEventListener{

private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

Sensor mSensor;
SensorManager mSensorManager;
String toastString = "";

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyWakeLock");
    wakeLock.acquire();


    Toast.makeText(this, "onCreate Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startid) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onStart Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    //record some data from the accelerometer
    quit();
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}

private void quit(){
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(MyService.this);
    wakeLock.release();
    this.stopSelf();
}
}
```

And I keep on getting the toasts from my `MyService` class telling me that my `onCreate` and `onStart` were successfully instantiated, even after calling my `cancelAlarm` method.

Comment: Can you post your AlarmReceiver code?

Comment: and your MyService class

Comment: @AndrewEl-Masry Added both

Comment: Do you have the broadcast receiver registered in the android  manifest?

Comment: Why are you using `ALARM_ID` on creation, and `alarmId` on cancel?

Comment: @AndrewEl-Masry yes, I have my `AlarmReciever` class registered in my manifest

Comment: @DanielNugent they are actually the same thing, I just pass `ALARM_ID` to `alarmId` in `cancelAlarm(int alarmId)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use same `PendingIntent` that you used while creating `Alarm`. Use `AlarmReceiver.class` instead of `AlarmManager.class` in your `Intent`:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
```

**Update `cancelAlarm()` method as below:**

```
private void cancelAlarm(int alarmId){
    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, alarmId, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(sender);
    sender.cancel();
}
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: is adding the `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` the only change here? If so I just tested it and it has no effect.

Comment: No, Use `AlarmReceiver.class` instead of `AlarmManager.class` in your Intent >> `Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);`